# In VIM how can I delete all lines until a regex is met?

Tags: vim

I am sure this has been answered, but the query is a bit too complex for google.

In short, I am trying to delete many deprecated methods from some code.  So I am skimming the file and when I see a method that I want to remove, I am deleting every line until I see a line that starts with a tab then the string "def".

I am thinking VIM should let me create a simple macro to do this, but the trick is escaping me.

Here is the kind of thing I want to remove.

```
def Method_to_Delete(self):
    """


    @return Control ID :
    @author
    """
    results = {}
    results['xx'] = "thingy"
    results['yy'] = 'thingy2'
    return results

def Method_to_Keep(self):
    """
     This is a method that does something wonderful!!!

    @return Control ID :
    @author
    """
    results = {}
    results['xxx'] = "WhooHoo!"
    results['yyy'] = 'yippee!!'
    return results
```

I want to have the cursor on the line with "def Method_to_Delete" and do something that will delete up until but not including "def Method_to_Keep"

There has got to be a better way than multiple "dd" commands.

Comment: Inside vim, see `:help d` and notice that when a pattern is used for `{motion}`, it spans lines.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Vim searches are actually text objects! That means you can simply:

```
d/\s*def
```

Then, simply repeat the command with `.` as desired.

Comment: You beat me to it, but I think you mean `d/\tdef`.

Comment: Cool!  Real close but not quite.  I guess I was a little unclear.
I want to delete the entire line I am on so I get rid of the current "def" line

Comment: So I have the cursor on a line with a "def" and I want to delete that line and every line up to, but not including the next line that starts with "\s\s\s\sdef"  (my tabs are always expanded)

Comment: I would search through the file with `/^def`, then use `n` and `N` to move around, then finally delete with `d/^def`. If you need to get to the start of the line, use `0`

Comment: If you have whitespace before the def, make the search `/\v^\s*def`

Comment: It is always four spaces, so the \s\s\s\s works a little more precisely.

Comment: @SkipHuffman: you can also just type four spaces :-) `d/    def` (they don't show up in this comment, I'm afraid)

Comment: true.  What is the "\v"?  I am thinking I should know it, but it is escaping me. (The invisible spaces is why \s is my preference)

Comment: Thanks!  I love how VI can turn two hours worth of scut work into ten minutes.  (And how stackoverflow can help me get better at what I do.)

Answer (score 17):

Use the `:delete` ex-command with a range

```
:,/Keep/-1d
```

Explanation

- The full command would be `:.,/Keep/-1delete`
- `.,/Keep/-1` is the range in which the `delete` command will act
- `.` means the current line.
- b/c we are using an range and starting from the current position the `.` can be assumed and dropped
- `/Keep/` search for the line that matches "Keep"
- `/Keep/-1` is search for the line that matches then subtract one line
- `:delete` can be shorted to `:d`

For more help see

```
:h :range
:h :d
```

Comment: This `-1` is exactly what i was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If a regex is needed, just type:

```
:%s/\_.*\(def Method_to_Keep\)/\1/g
```